# Is the $C[-1, 1]$ complete in $||f|| = \sqrt{\int_{-1}^{1}{f^{2}(t) dt}}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm considering the following problem:

For a given space $H = C[-1, 1]$ with inner product $(f, g) = \int_{-1}^{1}{f(t) g(t) dt}$ i'm considering a subspace $H_{0} = \{f \in H | \int_{-1}^{0}{f(t) dt } = \int_{0}^{1}{f(t) dt}\}$. The goals are the following: to show that it is a closed subspace and to establish, whether $H = H \oplus H^{\perp}$ holds.

Firstly, since we know that for any bounded (equivalently, continous) linear functional on normed space $X$, its kernel is closed (for the case of linear functionals the reverse statement also holds), i would like to find $l: X \to \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$), so that its kernel is $H_{0}$. For example, $l(\varphi)=\int_{-1}^{0}{\varphi(t) dt} - \int_{0}^{1}{\varphi(t)dt}$ satisfy the condition. Since any function from $H$,  is continous, then it's bounded (since $[-1, 1]$ is compact) and Riemann-integrable, so the $l(\varphi)$ is bounded, then it's kernel is closed, then $H_{0}$ is closed.

The second part relies on the theorem, which states the following: if X is  a Hilbert space and $X_{0} \subset X$ is a closed normed space, then $X^{\perp}$ is closed and $X = X_{0} \oplus X_{0}^{\perp}$.

In order to proceed it, i need to to prove that $C[-1, 1]$ is a Hilbert space, equivalently, to prove that it's  complete in $||f|| = \sqrt{(f, f)}$ norm. It's known that this space is complete in uniform norm, by the way, it's an infinte-dimensional space, so i can't state that it's complete in any other norm.

The question is how to prove the previous statement.

Any sort of help would be mush appreciated.

Comment: No, it's not complete; the completion is $L^2[-1,1]$, the (classes of equivalence, with respect to equality almost everywhere, of) functions whose square is Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: It is not a Hilbert space in the norm induced by the inner product. Take for example $f_{n}(x) = \arctan(nx)$

Comment: @TheOscillator Thanks, the counterexample clearly shows its uncompletness.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the suggestion, are there any way to obtain that the completition is precisely $L^{2}[-1, 1]$?

Comment: @Arteom What's required is essentially all the theory of Lebesgue integration. `;-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your space $X$, which is $C[-1,1]$ under the $L^{2}$ norm, is not complete, it does have an orthonormal basis consisting of
$$
           \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{2}\cos(\pi x),\frac{1}{2}\sin(\pi x),\frac{1}{2}\cos(2\pi x),\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\pi x),\cdots
$$
Using this basis $\{ v_n \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$, you do in fact get
$$
       \|f-\sum_{n=0}^{N}(f,v_n)v_n\|_{L^{2}}\rightarrow 0,\;\; \mbox{ as } N\rightarrow\infty,\;\;\; f \in C[-1,1].
$$
So the completion can be considered to be $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{+})$ if you like because the following is a dense isometric embedding into the complete space $\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{+})$ 
$$
                f \in X \mapsto \{(f,v_n)\}_{n=0}^{\infty}\in \ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{+}).
$$